# Does the command listen apply to Unix Datagram Sockets?

Tags: unix-sockets

Unix Datagram Sockets:
family = AF_UNIX/AF_LOCAL
type = SOCK_DGRAM

If I want to start a server for this type of socket, do I need to mark it as listening by calling 'listen' ? I was under the impression that listen only works for connection-oriented sockets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `listen()` won't work on a datagram socket since there is no connection to set up or tear down.  After you `bind()` the socket you can immediately begin sending packets by using `sendto()` to specify the recipient address.  You can use `recv()` or even `read()` to receive packets, but you should use `recvfrom()` if you also want to know who sent the packet (e.g. so you can reply to them).

If you want to talk to a specific host, you *can* (but don't need to) use `connect()` on a datagram socket.  In this case, `connect()` won't actually establish a connection with the remote host; it will just set the socket's default destination, so you can use functions like `send()` or `write()` that don't let you specify a destination.